# Confused about definition of absorption probability

Tags: probability, markov-process

My confusion can probably most easily be explained with an example. Consider the following one step transition matrix :
$$
  P=\matrix{%
    & 0 & 1  & 2  & 3   & 4 \\
    0 & 1/5  & 1/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 2/5 \\
    1 & 0 & 1/3  & 0 & 2/3 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0  & 1/2 \\
    3 & 0 & 3/5 & 0 & 2/5 & 0 \\
    4 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2
  }$$(*I annotated each column and row with the respective corresponding state*)

Clearly there are two closed classes $\{2,4\}, \{1,3\}$, and one open class consisting of the single transient state $0$. Now what I don't understand is, say I was looking for the probability of absorption into $\{1,3\}$ from $0$.

Is this simply $1/5$, or do you ignore the probability of remaining in the transient state ($1/5$), and recalculate accordingly to have it be $1/4$?

**Or more generally**, does "probability of absorption into class $X$" ignore the probability of remaining in the transient state, or do you take the probability directly?

Comment: If it were $1/5$ then the other probability of absorption would be $1/5+2/5=3/5$ and their sum would be $1/5+3/5=4/5<1$... Instead, the most usual approach works: for every $x$, call $a_x$ the probability of absorption into $\{1,3\}$ starting from $x$, then $a_1=a_3=1$, $a_2=a_4=0$ (right?), and $a_0=a_0/5+a_1/5+a_2/5+0a_3+2a_4/5$, from which $a_0=1/4$ follows. This approach works for every Markov chain.

Comment: @Did I've never seen that approach, my prof didn't teach us that, that's interesting. So the absorption probabilities ___do___ have to sum to 1 then? In this case they would evidently be $1/4$ and $3/4$ then.

Comment: "my prof didn't teach us that" Then asking them how you were supposed to approach the question seems mandatory (and I would be interested in their answer).

Comment: @Did I'm in engineering and taking a statistics course I circumvented some prereqs for with good grades, my guess is it was assumed we knew that :P nothing in our notes about how to actually _calculate_ absorption probabilities, unfortunately. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another brute-force, extremely inelegant method (perhaps acceptable in an overview of Markov chains in an engr course) would be to find a high power of the transition matrix, and look at its first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this simply 1/5 , or do you ignore the probability of remaining in the transient state (1/5 ), and recalculate accordingly to have it be 1/4 ?

If you are in state 0 at the start of a step, you can *immediately* either transition into $\{1,3\}$ (via state $1$, with probability $\tfrac 1 5$), remain in state $0$ ( with probability $\tfrac 1 5$), transition into either entry into $\{2,4\}$ (with probability $\tfrac 3 5$).  If you remain, you repeat this in the next step.  If you enter $\{2,4\}$ you will never reach $\{1,3\}$.

So the probability of *eventually* entering into the closed class $\{1,3\}$, is $$\overbrace{\qquad\qquad\qquad\tfrac 1 5 +}^{\text{immediately enter }\{1,3\}} \overbrace{\tfrac 1 5(\tfrac 1 5+ \tfrac 1 5(\tfrac 1 5 + \tfrac 1 5(\ldots)))\qquad\qquad\qquad}^{\text{immediately remain in } 0\text{, but eventually enter }\{1,3\}} = \frac{\tfrac 1 5}{\tfrac 1 5 + \tfrac 3 5} = \tfrac  1 4$$

**tl;dr** Yes, you have to recalibrate, if you want to find the probability of *eventually* entering a state rather than *immediately*.

Answer (score 1):

NOT AN ANSWER; continuation of my Comment. (See Answer just now
by @GrahamKemp.)

Computation in R. (Mathematical software may do the job more elegantly.)

```
 P = matrix(c(1/5, 1/5, 1/5,  0,  2/5,
                0,  1/3,  0,  2/3,  0,
                0,   0,  1/2,  0,  1/2,
                0,  3/5,  0,  2/5,  0,
                0,   0,  1/2,  0,  1/2), byrow=T, nrow=5)

 P2 = P %*% P;  P4 = P2 %*% P2;  P8 = P4 %*% P4;  P8
 ##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
 ## [1,] 2.56e-06 0.1184156 0.3749978 0.1315838 0.3750003
 ## [2,] 0.00e+00 0.4736977 0.0000000 0.5263023 0.0000000
 ## [3,] 0.00e+00 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
 ## [4,] 0.00e+00 0.4736721 0.0000000 0.5263279 0.0000000
 ## [5,] 0.00e+00 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000

 rowSums(P8)  # reality check
 ##  1 1 1 1 1

 P2 = P %*% P;  P4 = P2 %*% P2;  P8 = P4 %*% P4

 round(P8, 4)
 ##      [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]  [,5]
 ## [1,]    0 0.1184 0.375 0.1316 0.375
 ## [2,]    0 0.4737 0.000 0.5263 0.000
 ## [3,]    0 0.0000 0.500 0.0000 0.500
 ## [4,]    0 0.4737 0.000 0.5263 0.000
 ## [5,]    0 0.0000 0.500 0.0000 0.500
```

Already for $\text{P}^8,$ we have 'almost-absorption'
probabilities $.1184 + .1316 = .25$ and $.375 + .375 = .75,$
correct to four places.
Absorption by the 8th transition is all but certain. (Not
rounding to 4 places, the "0" in at upper-left is
$2.56 x 10^{-06}.$)

This approach may help you understand what is going on,
even if it is not a mathematically acceptable answer
in your course. (Notice, for example, that *exact* 0's throughout
$\text{P}^8$ show lack of communication between
the two closed classes.)

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a question about terminology than the underlying mathematics (which you seem to understand just fine).  Absent any other context, I would understand "the probability of absorption into $\{1, 3\}$" to refer to the probability of absorption into that pair of states *eventually* (and therefore the probability is $1/4$); in order to interpret it differently, I would expect it to be phrased as something like "the probability of *immediate* absorption into $\{1, 3\}$," and then the probability is $1/5$.

Comment: Yes, in terms of Markov chains, the event of absorption into a state is that of *eventually* entering that state (from some initial state), rather than immediately.